# path for downloading file not working

Tags: php, html

i am creating xml file to be downloaded but the link is not working. What is wrong with my code?

```
$xlsfile = 'localhost/debug/front/Aging_'.date("dmY_hiA").".xml";

echo "<br/>Start writeData<br/>"; 
$xml->writeData("$xlsfile");

echo '<a href="'.$xlsfile.'">'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/debug/'.$xlsfile.'</a>';

$message .= 'Extraction as of '.date("h:i A  d M Y").' can now be downloaded <a href="'.$xlsfile.'"><strong>here</strong></a><br>';
```

thank you in advance

Comment: can you try adding a download attribute to your anchor tag?
Rewrite as <a href="'.$xlsfile.'" download><strong>here</strong></a>

Comment: @KevinSunny i tried and it's worked but there is no data inside the file. why?

Comment: can you verify the addresses to the file? also check for the return of writedata method?

Comment: Happy to be of help. :)

Comment: @KevinSunny  
i am sorry i am here again. the link is worked when i downloaded it from browser, but if i send using email, it can't be downloaded. why?

Answer (score 2):

Use a download attribute to the anchor tag. Rewrite as `<a href="'.$xlsfile.'" download><strong>here</strong></a>`. Also correct your addresses to file.

Comment: i am sorry i am here again. the link is worked when i downloaded it from browser, but if i send using email, it can't be downloaded. why?

Comment: for that the href attribute should contain the absolute uri to file as value, instead of relative address. so put it as href="http://<address to file>"

Comment: if this is on a web server, you need to replace localhost with current hostname.

Comment: i tried that but it's show an error from opening file

Comment: can you share a screen capture?

Comment: i am not allowed to post any image. but here is my error.
Warning: fopen(hostname/debug/front/Aging_19052015_0313PM.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/oct/auto/ExcelWriterXML.php on line 362 
Not able to open "hostname/debug/front/Aging_19052015_0313PM.xml" for writing

Comment: what is your hostname? btw you can add scrrenshot by uploading it on imgur and sharing the link here

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bygtg3kMy9oRNjdwTGZWdHpiMkE/view?usp=sharing 
here is the error @Kevin Sunny

Answer (score 0):

As I seen you are asking in the comments to other answers, This wont work when you send this as email to someone because, the file is generated/stored in your localhost. Localhost is your machine. Others wont have access to your localhost.

To have this available for everyone, you need to get a hosting and host the script there.